# Django DRF | Modify parent model field while creating a Child model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a User model and another Admin model which has a OneToOne relationship with User model.

I am trying to modify a field in User model while an Admin model is being created.

Here is my Serializer for admin model:

```
class AdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A Serizlier class for vendor """

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Admin
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'gender')

        # This didn't work, also user_type is a field in User model and not Admin model
        read_only_fields = ('user_type',)


    def create(self, validated_data): # override this method <<<
        """
        Since the "user" is a read_only field, the validated data doesn't contain it.
        """

        # Line that causes the error. Trying to modify User model field
        validated_data['user_type'] = constants.Constants.ADMIN
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

but I get an error:

> The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by
>   default. Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer
>   `letzbargain_api.serializers.AdminSerializer`, or set `read_only=True`
>   on nested serializer fields

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add your `UserSerializer` serializer and `Admin` & `User` models?

Comment: is user_type is a field of user model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to create `Admin`, but want to keep `Admin`'s `user`'s `user_type` read-only.

To do that you have to make sure `user_type` is read-only in your specified user serializer of `AdminSerializer`. For example, I am writing a new serializer:

```
class AdminUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('foo', 'bar', 'user_type')
        read_only_fields = ('user_type',)
```

Now use that one in your `AdminSerializer`:

```
class AdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = AdminUserSerializer() # make sure user_type is read-only in whatever serializer you specify here

    class Meta:
        model = models.Admin
        fields = ('user', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'gender')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = models.User.objects.create(**user_data, user_type=constants.Constants.ADMIN)
        admin = models.Admin.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return admin
```